# Unexpected WebView content appearance

Tags: android, android-webview

Trying to get the same look for `TextView` and `WebView` content, I've met a strong resistance of Android 4.

As `Display` `getWidth()` is deprecated, I've tried hardcoded values for Android 4 but the result is the same: at `webView` the text becomes larger and the scrolling appears while the `textView` font size is decreased.

Such a behavior for the same display type does not make any sense for me, could anyone please let me know if that is documented anywhere ?

---

**Solution:**
As `pt` seemed to be ignored by WebView, I had to use `px` scaled as much closer to `sp` as I can:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,24);

font-size: " + pixelsToSp(this, 24.0f) + "px;

private float scaledPX(Context context, Float px) {
    return TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, px, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

---

Android 2.3 WVGA

[image: Android 2.3]

Android 4.1 WVGA

[image: Android 4.1]

Layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="same text"/>

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Code

```
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1)).getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1)).getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1)).getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN); // this line was missed when the screenshots was made, it makes the images being scaled correctly

((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,24);
final String width = Integer.toString(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth());
final String html = "<html style = 'margin: 0px; padding: 0px;'>"
        + "<head>"
        + "<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; user-scalable=no; initial-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; target-densityDpi=device-dpi;'/>"
        + "</head>"
        + "<body style = '"
        + "width: "
        + width
        + "px;"
        + ";'>"
        + "<div style='overflow: hidden; width: 100%; font-size: " + 24 + "px;'>"
        + "same text size"
        + "<img style='max-width: " + width + "px;' src=\"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Niobe050905-Siamese_Cat.jpeg\"/>"
        + "</div>"
        + "</body>";

((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1)).loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What devices are you testing on? I suspect that it has more to do with the scaling based on screen rather than the version of android itself.

The `setTextSize(float size)` method uses the scaled pixels unit (sp). The html is using the pt unit which I don't think will take into consideration the display resolution like sp will.

Try like this:

```
((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PT,24);
```

That should use the pt unit instead of sp. Which *might* make the text appear the same as inside the WebView. Another thing to consider however, is that WebView has a zoom factor. Even if the fonts are the same size the WebView could be zoomed in/out whereas a default TextView cannot, which would also result in the fonts being different sizes on the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, I can see the problem of using setTextSize with a single parameter.For the webView textZoom is set to 100, that was one of the first things I've checked as mainly the text size seems to be affected, the images are not looking up- or down-scaled. I'm doing tests now with two emulators having the same WVGA skin and only different API levels, so I expect them to have the same display parameters, could it be incorrect ?

Comment: Tried to use `COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` for textView and `px` for `webView`, the font size is still different.

Comment: @A-Live Hmm, I got nothing else then. However I would suggest you start testing on devices ASAP. Would be a shame to go through all of the trouble of getting it working in the emulator only to find out that there is a different issue (or even no issue at all) with devices.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I found the WebView actually ignoring `pt`and `sp` size attributes, so the solution was to try converting `sp` to `px` for CSS. I'm not very satisfied with how it works, better than nothing though. I believe the problem appears with devices.